# 3Ware RAID6 array sometimes hanging. Undetected broken disk?

Tags: 3ware

We have a Debian server with 3Ware 9650SE 8-drive RAID controller, with 5 disk RAID6 array, acting as virtual machine host, all Linux. Problems keep occurring and I suspect an undetected broken disk.

We have had several crashes now where both host and all guests are saying that the IO system blocked for 120 seconds or more. We suspected a faulty RAID controller, but we replaced it with an identical one with identical firmware, which didn't fix it. I didn't think it would, because a second RAID1 array kept working properly.

Almost a week ago (Sunday), when this was acting up, the auto verify was at 66%. Last night (friday morning) it was at 67%. Both before and after booting, and both while experiencing problems. When I turned off the verify with `tw_cli /c0/u0 stop verify`, things became responsive again.

I suspect it got stuck on a disk fault at around 66%. An auto verify starts on Saturday:

```
# tw_cli /c0 show verify
/c0 basic verify weekly preferred start: Saturday, 12:00AM
```

and would normally be long done by Friday. Seeing as how Sunday was 66% and Friday was 67%, it's unlikely to be coincidence.

'smartctl -a -d 3ware,0 /dev/twa0' and 'smartctl -t long' (long SMART self test) on all the drives didn't reveal any errors. Neither does `tw_cli /c0 show alarms`.

I suspected a disk is broken in a way that is hard to detect, but I took each drive out of the array one by one, created a 'single' array from it and dd'ed full of zeros. No disk showed errors.

Or any other advice?

Edit:

this is the layout:

```
# tw_cli /c0 show

Unit  UnitType  Status         %RCmpl  %V/I/M  Stripe  Size(GB)  Cache  AVrfy
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
u0    RAID-6    OK             -       -       256K    5587.9    RiW    OFF    
u1    SPARE     OK             -       -       -       1863.01   -      OFF    
u2    RAID-1    OK             -       -       -       1862.63   RiW    ON     

VPort Status         Unit Size      Type  Phy Encl-Slot    Model
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
p0    OK             u0   1.82 TB   SATA  0   -            ST32000542AS        
p1    OK             u0   1.82 TB   SATA  1   -            ST32000542AS        
p2    OK             u0   1.82 TB   SATA  2   -            ST32000542AS        
p3    OK             u0   1.82 TB   SATA  3   -            ST32000542AS        
p4    OK             u0   1.82 TB   SATA  4   -            ST32000542AS        
p5    OK             u1   1.82 TB   SATA  5   -            WDC WD2002FYPS-02W3 
p6    OK             u2   1.82 TB   SATA  6   -            WDC WD2002FYPS-02W3 
p7    OK             u2   1.82 TB   SATA  7   -            WDC WD2002FYPS-02W3 

Name  OnlineState  BBUReady  Status    Volt     Temp     Hours  LastCapTest
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bbu   On           Yes       OK        OK       OK       0      xx-xxx-xxxx
```

The unit in question is u0.

edit2:

tw_cli /c0 show diag shows something interesting (edit3: this is harmless, I found out it's caused by calling `smartctl -a -d 3ware,X /dev/twa0` where X is an invalid port):

```
QueueAtaPassthrough() called with invalid TargetHandle: 0x17, portHandle: 0xFF

Legacy opcode=0xB1 error=0x10E

E=010E T=14:15:51     : Invalid operation for specified port
E=010E T=14:15:51 U=0 : Return error status to host
Error, Unit 23: Invalid operation for specified port
(EC:0x10e, SK=0x05, ASC=0x24, ASCQ=0x00, SEV=01, Type=0x70)
No additional sense data
Error, Unit 23: 0x10E OVERRIDDEN due to invalid sense buffer descriptor
sense buffer: len=0, address=0x414ca2c7c
Send AEN (code, time): 0031h, 06/21/2013 14:26:16
Synchronize host/controller time
(EC:0x31, SK=0x00, ASC=0x00, ASCQ=0x00, SEV=04, Type=0x71)
```

I get tons of these. I have no idea what it means though. I can't even make out which unit or port it is. (edit3: I do know now, it's harmless).

Given my edit3, I'm back to square one. Nothing indicates a disk is broken, except that the verify hangs at 66% and causes the array to hang, which also sometimes happens randomly. I wish the verify would find the fault...

Comment: What HDDs? Are they officially supported?

Comment: I added the layout. The disks are ST32000542AS. They are supported, but more over, the server worked fine for 3 years.

Comment: I had issue with some WD drives becoming verrryyyy slow at some point. only a hdparm (not doable here sadly) showed me a throughoutput of ~300KB/s (yes K!) instead of the usual 80~100MB/s.

Comment: the difference between the Enterprise and the disks of desktop drives is that they work out the bugs. 

If Enterprise drives encounters any error, the disc falls out of the raid. (as in companies sensitive to the risks of storing data and are willing to pay for it) 

If a desktop drive meets the fault, it will try to last until all timeouts will end. (As users one drive, and to the data they need to reach, and if they fall out discs at once, the manufacturer will be very painful) 

apparently ST32000542AS is quiet and economical desktop version discs.

for example http://goo.gl/rWb5lj

Comment: Actually, just recently, this server suddenly hung, differently and more severely than the original problem, and the logs showed a timeout on a RAID port. The timeout was on one of the enterprise drives (of which this server has more now).

Answer (score 1):

2 things that were not brought up so far:

1. Is this a SATA RAID controller? If so, SATA cables are prone to aging and replacing them might solve such issues easily. Most of the time this can be tried when disk errors, lags, timeouts occur but the SMART values are all ok and the drive passes all self tests. Unfortunately finding a good SATA cable vender is difficult.
2. 3Ware RAID controllers are old and unsupported these days. You will neither get firmware upgrades nor spare parts. In case your controller dies the RAID might be unrecoverable without the matching controller AND firmware. An expensive data recovery is then needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, what is your firmware version?

There was an issue I experienced - which sounds a lot like what you are describing - when following requirements are met:

- 3ware 96xx series controller
- RAID 6
- 256k Stripe Size
- Firmware version < v4.10.00.021*

At the time there was no firmware fix available so I migrated from 256k to 64k stripe size which also solved the issue. You could try as workaround, though it certainly will take days to complete.

Later on I tried the new firmware (* 4.10.00.021 I think had the fix) with 256k and worked like a charm. 4.10.00.027 is the latest version.

Comment: We don't have the problem anymore. Verification always succeeded. We did however get a complete server hang some months ago (after a long time of no problems). Dmesg said that disk x timed out. I don't know why the controller didn't kick it, but even though it wasn't explicitly marked as degraded, I replaced it. And, other disks have been replaced since then as well. So it's likely it was a disk issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be due to one of the disks encountering a read error and blocking the entire array until it either manages to reallocate the sector or the RAID controller assumes the drive is dead and boots it out of the array, marking it as "Degraded" (this is completely up to the controller in question). This may happen often if a disk is starting to die but still passes SMART. Most consumer disks will continue to attempt the read forever.

This issue is solved in some drives destined for RAID using something called [Error recovery control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_recovery_control). WD calls this TLER. From the site:

`RAID-specific time-limited error recovery (TLER) - Pioneered by WD, this feature prevents drive fallout caused by the extended hard drive error-recovery processes common to desktop drives.`

Basically, it tells a disk that if it cannot read a sector, to give up after x seconds. This is great in a RAID since the data may be recovered from another disk.

From what I've read, the ST32000542AS does not implement any form of ERC so any of them can block the entire array. The WD2002FYPS does in fact implement WD's TLER so they will not cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have issues with a 3ware controller and Seagate drives. There's a subtle firmware incompatibility. I switched to Samsung drives, problem solved.